# CSS Flex items vertically and then horizontally

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

If container has fixed width and height, is it possible to move child elements to next line until there is enough space vertically and then, when there it no more vertical space, make last line child element take width space.

It is hard to verbally expain what I want to achieve, so here is JsFiddle of what I currently have: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sportik777/7gpc1Los/1/)

```css
.parent {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  width: 160px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 4px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Image of what I would like to achieve:

[image: EXPECTED RESULT]

Answer (score 0):

You can have something similar if you use a column direction. In this case, the overflow will occur on the right and not on the bottom:

```css
.parent {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  width: 160px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 4px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works almost like it is necessary, but not exactly. In your solution if I add one more child (8th), then it will take over the second row. But it should not be shown, it should be located on the right side of 7th child, out of the parent block.

Comment: @sportik yes I know, that's why I said it's *similar* not an exact solution ;)  I simply changed the overflow direction to approximate your needs and gave you a way to go